# Filtering sound on a DE2 FPGA

Tags: vhdl

HI I am building a filter in VHDL, when I program it in the DE2 board the sound goes throught input port of the FPGA and out to the speakers not problem but when I move a switch to high to activate the filter no sound comes out. I have no clue what is the problem. I will attach the code with the hope of that you can help me to find the bug.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY lowpass_iir IS
    PORT (readdata_left,readdata_right  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 DOWNTO 0);
        outL,outR                       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(23 DOWNTO 0);
        CLOCK_50                        : IN  STD_LOGIC);
END lowpass_iir;

ARCHITECTURE fpga OF lowpass_iir IS
    SIGNAL xL, yL, xR, yR               : SIGNED(23 downto 0):=others=>'0');

BEGIN
    PROCESS (CLOCK_50)    -- Calculates the first coeffitient
        CONSTANT a1:INTEGER:= (1+1/2-1/4-1/8+1/16+1/32+1/64-1/128+1/256+1/512-1/1024+1/2048);
        CONSTANT a2:INTEGER:= -(1+1/2+1/4-1/8-1/16+1/32-1/64+1/128-1/256-1/512-1/1024-1/2048+1/4096);
        CONSTANT a3:INTEGER:= (1/2+1/4-1/8+1/16+1/32+1/64-1/128-1/256-1/512-1/1024+1/2048-1/4096+1/8192);
        CONSTANT a4:INTEGER:= -(1/2-1/4+1/8-1/16+1/32-1/64+1/128-1/256-1/512-1/1024+1/2048-1/4096-1/8192);
        CONSTANT b0:INTEGER:= (1/2-1/4-1/8+1/16+1/32+1/64-1/128+1/256+1/512-1/1024+1/2048);
        CONSTANT b1:INTEGER:= -(1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16-1/32+1/64+1/128-1/256+1/512+1/1024-1/2048-1/4096);
        CONSTANT b2:INTEGER:= (1+1/2-1/4+1/8+1/16-1/32-1/64+1/128-1/256-1/512-1/1024+1/2048-1/4096);
        CONSTANT b3:INTEGER:= -(1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16-1/32+1/64+1/128-1/256+1/512+1/1024-1/2048-1/4096);
        CONSTANT b4:INTEGER:= (1/2-1/4-1/8+1/16+1/32+1/64-1/128+1/256+1/512-1/1024+1/2048);  

        variable yl0,yl1,yl2,yl3,yl4,ylf    : integer;
        variable xl0,xl1,xl2,xl3,xl4        : integer;
        variable yr0,yr1,yr2,yr3,yr4,yrf,c  : integer:=0;
        variable xr0,xr1,xr2,xr3,xr4        : integer:=0;

    BEGIN
        IF (CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1') THEN
            xL  <= signed(readdata_left);
            xR  <= signed(readdata_right);
            IF (C <4) THEN c:=c+1; END IF;
            case c is
                when 1 =>--y(0)= b0x(0)
                -- LEFT OUTPUT
                xl0 := to_integer(xL);
                yl0 := b0*xl0;
                -- RIGHT OUTPUT
                xr0 := to_integer(xR);
                yr0 := b0*xr0;
                -- output
                ylf  := yl0; 
                yrf := yr0;  

            when 2 => --y(1)= b0x(1)+b1x(0)+a1y(0) 
                xl1 := to_integer(xL);
                yl1 := b0*xl1
                      +b1*xl0+a1*yl0;

                xr1 := to_integer(xR);
                yr1 := b0*xr1
                      +b1*xr0+a1*yr0;
                -- output 
                ylf := yl1;
                yrf := yr1; 

            when 3 =>--y(2)= b0x(2)+b1x(1)+a1y(1)+b2x(0)-a2y(0)
                xl2 := to_integer(xL);
                yl2 := b0*xl2
                      +b1*xl1+a1*yl1
                      +b2*xl0+a2*yl0;

                xr2 := to_integer(xR);
                yr2 := b0*xr2
                      +b1*xr1+a1*yr1
                      +b2*xr0+a2*yr0;
                -- output
                ylf := yl2;
                yrf := yr2; 

            when 4 =>--y(3)= b0x(3)+b1x(2)+a1y(2)+b2x(1)-a2y(1)+b3x(0)+a3y(0)
                xl3 := to_integer(xL);
                yl3:= b0*xl3
                     +b1*xl2+a1*yl2
                     +b2*xl1+a2*yl1
                     +b3*xl0+a3*yl0;

                xr3 := to_integer(xR);
                yr3 := b0*xr3
                      +b1*xr2+a1*yr2
                      +b2*xr1+a2*yr1
                      +b3*xr0+a3*yr0;
                -- output  
                ylf := yl3;
                yrf := yr3;         

            when others =>--y(n)= b0x(n)+b1x(n-1)+a1y(n-1)+b2x(n-2)-a2y(n-2)+b3x(n-3)+a3y(n-3)  
                xl4 := to_integer(xL);
                yl4:= b0*xl4
                     +b1*xl3+a1*yl3
                     +b2*xl2+a2*yl2
                     +b3*xl1+a3*yl1
                    +b4*xl0+a4*yl0;
                xl0 := xl1;
                xl1 := xl2;
                xl2 := xl3;
                xl3 := xl4;
                yl0 := yl1;
                yl1 := yl2;
                yl2 := yl3;
                yl3 := yl4;

                xr4 := to_integer(xR);
                yr4 := b0*xr4
                      +b1*xr3+a1*yr3
                      +b2*xr2+a2*yr2
                      +b3*xr1+a3*yr1
                      +b4*xr0+a4*yr0;
                xr0 := xr1;
                xr1 := xr2;
                xr2 := xr3;
                xr3 := xr4;
                yr0 := yr1;
                yr1 := yr2;
                yr2 := yr3;
                yr3 := yr4;
                -- output
                ylf := yl4;
                yrf := yr4;         
            end case;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    yL <= TO_SIGNED(ylf,24);
    yR <= TO_SIGNED(yrf,24);
    outL <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(yL); -- Left output 
    outR <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(yR); -- Right output 

END fpga;
```

Comment: For a start, those fractional expressions aren't going to produce useful integer constants. Are all your coefficients actually 0? Was the output the correct amplitude when you simulated this filter?

Comment: My simulation in matlab gave me the following coefficients:                                  b= (0.2320   -0.9279    1.3919   -0.9279    0.2320)
a= (1.0000   -1.6147    1.5788   -0.7201    0.3292)                                           the filte rworks good in matlab and I am trying to implement it on the FPGA

Comment: According with Digital Signal Processing with FPGAs book, that was the way to declare coefficients because will execute faster and floting point are not really a good practice in circuit building. If you have a better idea of how to implement this please let me know I have been researching a lot and I cannot find anything useful or clear to understand .. thanks

Comment: Simulate first - in ghdl or Modelsim for example - write a testbench and get it working there - before moving to FPGA.

Answer (score 0):

Hi these assignements will not work:

```
yL <= TO_SIGNED(ylf,24);
yR <= TO_SIGNED(yrf,24);
```

Indeed, you declare ylf & yrf as variables in a process. So they can't be used outside the process.

Comment: Why the assigment won't work? I do no't understand..           ylf and yrf are declared inside the process. This is the only process in this component so I guess that there is no risk of another process using it

Comment: ylf & yrf are declared as variables in a process, thus they are local variables. So you can not use them outside of this process like you do.

Comment: I totally miss that thaks I will fix that

Comment: I did declare it outside the process. I had it done before probably when I was cleanning the code (erasing extra comented lines) I moved to the wrong place. I also multiplied the floating point values by 10000 to make them integer and then divided by 10000 after the filtering was done. Besaides that, the code still the same. I ran the code againg and I get the sound with noise